# JPA EntityManager not being injected with Spring 4

Tags: java, dependency-injection, entitymanager, spring-4

After a couple of working exclusively with guice I'm attempting to reteach myself the spring framework in its current version, using annotations. However, I don't seem to be able to get spring to inject the `EntityManager` using the `@PersistenceContext` annotation during testing. Here's my setup:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="com.whatever.shop.database" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.whatever.shop.domain.Product</class>
        <class>com.whatever.shop.domain.Order</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"     value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"     value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

A generic DAO Implementation with the persistence context

```
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements GenericDAO<T, PK> {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="com.whatever.shop.database")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  private Class<T> entityType;

  public GenericDAOImpl(Class<T> entityType) {
    this.entityType = entityType;
  }

  @Override
  public T getById(PK id) {
    return entityManager.find(entityType, id);
  }

  // Some more methods
}
```

ProductDAOImpl

```
@Repository
public class ProductDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Product, Long> implements ProductDAO {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="com.whatever.shop.database")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public ProductDAOImpl() {
    super(Product.class);
  }
}
```

BeanConfig class, for class-defined bean definitions:

```
package com.whatever.shop.database;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.whatever.shop.database.jpa"})
public class BeanConfig {

  @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.whatever.shop.database");
  }

  @Bean
  public EntityManager entityManager() {
    return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
  }
}
```

And finally, the test class I'm attempting to inject into:

```
package com.whatever.shop.database.jpa;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.whatever.shop.database.BeanConfig;
import com.whatever.shop.domain.Product;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={BeanConfig.class})
public class ProductDAOTest {

  @Autowired
  private ProductDAO productDao;

  /**
   * Test method for {@link com.whatever.shop.database.GenericDAOImpl#getById(java.lang.Object)}.
   */
  @Test
  public void testGetById() {
    productDao.save(new Product());
  }
}
```

My understanding of how this should work is as follows

1. The test runner looks at the Application context bean and creates the `EntityManagerFactory`
2. The `@ComponentScan` annotation should loop through all of my DAO implementations, detecting the `@Repository` annotation and doing `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` type bits and bobs.

But whenever I run the test, I get a `NullPointerException` on the `EntityManager`. The bean is being instantiated but it's not being wired into the DAO.

Comment: You're not supposed to create an EntityManagerFactory by yourself. Read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-jpa

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
The problem here is that I was trying to treat `EntityManager` as I would `SessionFactory`. Spring needs its own factory objects to be present in the context so it knows what to do when it encounters the `@PersistenceContext` annotation. The changes are in the BeanConfig class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.whatever.shop.database.jpa"})
public class BeanConfig {

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean thing = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      thing.setPersistenceUnitName("com.whatever.shop.database");
      return thing;
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().nativeEntityManagerFactory);
      return transactionManager;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe set this answer as 'solved' by clicking on green check mark? :)